# Looping through columns in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to this VBA coding. I'm comparing data from previous columns and the code is suppose to paste the new data into a new column.

This works, because its a fixed column

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D100")
```

But I need the columns to be iterative, so I modified it and this is what I've tried, it doesn't work.

```
Dim n1 as Integer
Dim n3 as Integer
Dim Resultcol As Range
n1 = 1
n3 = 6
Do While n1 < 5
Set Resultcol = (Cells(2,n3), Cells(100,n3))
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Resultcol")
n3 = n3 + 2
n1 = n1 + 1
Loop
```

The whole code is like this:-

```
Sub commonality()
Dim n1 As Integer
Dim n2 As Integer
Dim n3 As Integer
Dim lotnum As Integer
Dim Resultcol As Range


'
' commonality Macro
' commonality
'
lotnum = InputBox("Number of lots to compare?" & vbCrLf & "Minimum 3 lots")
n1 = 1
n2 = 4
n3 = 6
Resultcol = Range(Cells(2, n3), Cells(100, n3))
Do While n1 < 4
    Sheets("Export_to_Excel").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Export_to_Excel (2)").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Export_to_Excel (3)").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EQPID"
    Range("D2").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=LOOKUP(""zzz"",CHOOSE({1,2},"""",INDEX(R2C[-3]:R100C[-3],MATCH(0,COUNTIF(R1C:R[-1]C,R2C[-3]:R100C[-3])+IF(IF(COUNTIF(R2C[-2]:R100C[-2],R2C[-3]:R100C[-3])>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(R2C[-1]:R100C[-1],R2C[-3]:R100C[-3])>0,1,0)=2,0,1),0))))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D100"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    n1 = 4
Loop
    
    
Do While n2 <= lotnum
    Range("D2:D100").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
    Sheets("Export_to_Excel (4)").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Export_to_Excel (5)").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Columns("F:F").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=LOOKUP(""zzz"",CHOOSE({1,2},"""",INDEX(R2C[-2]:R100C[-2],MATCH(0,COUNTIF(R1C:R[-1]C,R2C[-2]:R100C[-2])+IF(IF(COUNTIF(R2C[-1]:R100C[-1],R2C[-2]:R100C[-3])>0,1,0)=2,0,1),0))))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Resultcol), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("G2:G85").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-57
    Cells(n2, 14).Value = 1
    n2 = n2 + 1
    n3 = n3 + 2
Loop
End Sub
```

Any help?

Comment: Try `Destination:=Range(Resultcol)` without the quotes to refer to you range variable.

Comment: Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object' _Global' failed

Comment: The whole code is like this if it helps         Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=LOOKUP(""zzz"",CHOOSE({1,2},"""",INDEX(R2C[-2]:R100C[-2],MATCH(0,COUNTIF(R1C:R[-1]C,R2C[-2]:R100C[-2])+IF(IF(COUNTIF(R2C[-1]:R100C[-1],R2C[-2]:R100C[-3])>0,1,0)=2,0,1),0))))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Resultcol), Type:=xlFillDefault

Comment: If you get this to work it will copy the `Selection` to 5 different sets of column pairs. You don't need a loop for that. It probably doesn't work because your `Selection` is of a different size from the destination range. So, work on the `Selection` part.

Comment: Code to write a formula. Then, code to copy the formula. Too convoluted. Why not get the code to write the result? Or, at least, get the code to write the formulas where you want them? If you allow me to speak from experience, your formula is designed to keep you unhappy for life. Introducing VBA to it will shorten your unhappy life. Find another way, my friend.

Comment: The *whole code* should be in your question, not buried in comments. Please [edit] your post to put it there instead.

Comment: What is being selected before this runs, and how?  A single cell or ?

Comment: Supposed to be from row 2 to row 100